# listview or customview for chat app

Tags: android, listview, load, instant-messaging

I am developing a chat app. But i really care about performance. I don't know what view is better for chat activity. I saw an example project for a chat app that uses `Listview` and when a new message receives calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. but in this way the whole `listview` is reloaded and takes time to load on long lists. Are there other ways with better performance that I can create a new View for any new message?

Comment: How about a `ListView` with custom `Adaptor`

Comment: There are tons of examples on net, and believe me performance is the last thing you should be worried about when making a Chat App.. First make a working model.. The View / GUI can always be changed..

Comment: I'd recommend ListView, notifyDataSetChanged() does not reload all the listview items but only which are visible and near visible.

Comment: I am now searching in Telegram open source project to know how telegram do it.

Comment: The answer is not RecyclerView because of recycling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `"notifyItemInserted (int position)"` in RecyclerView.Adapter according to the documentation:

> Notify any registered observers that the item reflected at position
>   has been newly inserted. The item previously at position is now at
>   position position + 1. This is a structural change event.
>   Representations of other existing items in the data set are still
>   considered up to date and will not be rebound, though their positions
>   may be altered.

I think this is the answer but I am a little doubtful. any advice will be welcomed.